# How to shorten this syntax in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Can this (Google Sheet) `=IFS` syntax be improved?

```
=IFS(and(E42>E38;E42>E34;E42>E30;E42>E26;E42>E22;E42>E18); "Cattleman"; 
and(E38>E42;E38>E34;E38>E30;E38>E26;E38>E22;E38>E18); "Naturalist"; 
and(E34>E42;E34>E38;E34>E30;E34>E26;E34>E22;E34>E18); "Farmer"; 
and(E30>E42;E30>E38;E30>E34;E30>E26;E30>E22;E30>E18); "Carpenter"; 
and(E26>E42;E26>E38;E26>E30;E26>E34;E26>E22;E26>E18); "Blacksmith"; 
and(E22>E42;E22>E38;E22>E30;E22>E34;E22>E26;E22>E18); "Miner"; 
and(E18>E42;E18>E38;E18>E30;E18>E34;E18>E22;E18>E26); "Builder")
```

And how can I add a default value so that if this syntax returns `FALSE` it doesn't say `#N/A!` in the cell, but "No class" or something similar instead (or empty)?

Comment: @player0 Certainly not :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious way would be to replace the ANDs with a MAX. Why? In the first line, if E42 is greater than all of the other cells, it must be greater than the MAX of them. So the condition in this line

```
E42 > MAX(E38; E34; E30; E26; E22; E18)
```

which looks much cleaner. Repeat for the other lines.

Trying to simplify it more, the logic of the formula seems to be that depending on which of the cells is the greatest, you choose a particular literal value. There is a function for that! I'd try this (can't test it though without access to your data)

```
=CHOOSE(
   MATCH(
     MAX(E42; E38; E34; E30; E26; E22; E18);
     {E42; E38; E34; E30; E26; E22; E18});
   "Cattleman"; "Naturalist"; "Farmer"; "Carpenter"; "Blacksmith"; "Miner"; "Builder")
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap it in `IFERROR` like this:

```
=IFERROR(IFS(
 AND(E42>E38;E42>E34;E42>E30;E42>E26;E42>E22;E42>E18);"Cattleman";
 AND(E38>E42;E38>E34;E38>E30;E38>E26;E38>E22;E38>E18);"Naturalist"; 
 AND(E34>E42;E34>E38;E34>E30;E34>E26;E34>E22;E34>E18);"Farmer"; 
 AND(E30>E42;E30>E38;E30>E34;E30>E26;E30>E22;E30>E18);"Carpenter"; 
 AND(E26>E42;E26>E38;E26>E30;E26>E34;E26>E22;E26>E18);"Blacksmith"; 
 AND(E22>E42;E22>E38;E22>E30;E22>E34;E22>E26;E22>E18);"Miner"; 
 AND(E18>E42;E18>E38;E18>E30;E18>E34;E18>E22;E18>E26);"Builder");
 "No class")
```

Comment: Thanks! Was just looking at that, using an  IF statement still gives the #N/A value if one ore more cells have the same value. IFERROR solved it.